# SqlException: Invalid object name "User"

Tags: c#

Hi im getting this error where it says "SqlException: Invalid object name 'User'. even though i have build the application without errors and checked the application everything except this works, please do give me some suggetsions.

code:

```
 public async Task<User> Create(User user)
        {
            _context.User.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();//error happens here
            return user;
        }
```

Comment: If this is Entity Framework, did you run your migrations to actually set up your database? Are you connected to the right database? Have you verified with SQL Management Studio that the user table exists?

Comment: yes the table is callled users

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_context.Users.Add(user);` then if the table is `users`

Comment: Thank you so much man, been sitting on this error for days :)

Comment: If you have a `User` and a `Users` property in your DbContext, then you have much bigger problems here.

Comment: nope i fixed it and it works with the db context too so dont worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `_context.User.Add(user);` to `_context.Users.Add(user);`